# Is there a universal slug for static homepage?

Tags: page-template, homepage

I'm creating a theme where the homepage is a static page, but in the theme files it needs it's own php file like `page-home.php`. So far so good, but this only works if the homepage chosen in "reading settings" is called home. So my question is: is there a universal slug for the homepage which is always assigned to the page chosen as the homepage? Something like `page-universal-homepage.php`?

Comment: there is both `front-page.php` or `home.php` template depending on whether settings are for page or posts shown on front. see the visual hierarchy guide here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Comment: Oh right. How could I have forgotten this. Thanks a lot anyways.